# Every time I knit my R markdown to a documents, its gives me error code. You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. l.125 #

Tags: macros

`{r NHANES2006,echo = TRUE}
library(sm)
library("kdensity")
triglyceride <- read.table("C:/Users/thamo/OneDrive - University of South Africa/UNISA/MODULES/2021-2022/STA4809/ASSIGNMENT 02/NHANES2006.csv", head = TRUE, sep = ";")

y <- (triglyceride[ , c("TRG"), drop = FALSE])

kde = kdensity(y, start = "gamma", kernel = "normal")
plot(kde, main = "triglyceride")

````
The kernel density estimate shows that triglyceride data is negatively skewed,has 
sharper peak and have got a larger spread with a bandwidth of 10.16.

\item[(b)] Parametric density estimate for triglyceride.\\

```{r NHANES, echo = TRUE}
kde = kdensity((y), start = "gamma", kernel = "normal")
plot(kde, lwd = 2, col = "red",
     main = "Normal distribution parametric density estimates")
lines(kde, plot_start = TRUE, lty = 2, lwd = 2)
````

The parametric density estimate (dashed line) with bandwidth of 10.16, has less peak than kernel density estimate, also has larger spread on the right tail.
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Question 2}

```
library(sm)
library(rpanel)
library(tkrplot)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
n1 <- 50
mu1 <- 3
sigma1 <- 0.5
x1 <- rnorm(n1, mean = mu1, sd = sigma1)
sm.density(x1, model = "Normal", ylim = c(0,2),
xlab = "Normal(mean = 3, sd = 0.5) for n = 50")

n2 <- 200
mu2 <- 5
sigma2 <- 0.6
x2 <- rnorm(n2, mean = mu2, sd = sigma2)
sm.density(x2, model = "Normal", ylim = c(0,1.5),
xlab = "Normal(mean = 5, sd = 0.6) for n = 200")

n3 <- 100
mu3 <- 10
sigma3 <- 4
x3 <- rnorm(n3, mean = mu3, sd = sigma3)
sm.density(x3, model = "Normal", ylim = c(0,0.12),
xlab = "Normal(mean = 10, sd = 4) for n = 100")
```

From the above figures the density estimates for a given mean
and standard deviation various by sample size.

\textbf{Question 3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(a)]

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{The bias KDE is given by.}\
&E[\hat f_n(y) - f(y)] = E(\frac{1}{nh}\sum^n_{i=1} W(\frac{Y_i-y}{h})) - f(y)\
&=\frac{1}{h}E(W(\frac{Y_i-y}{h})) - f(y)\
&=\frac{1}{h}\int W(\frac{Y-y}{h})f(y)dy-f(y)\
\text{After some change of variables}\
&=\frac{1}{h}\int W(\frac{Y-y}{h})f(y)\frac{dy}{h}-f(y)\
&=\int W(y)f(y + hy)dy-f(y)\
\text{Using Taylor expansion when h is small}\
&f(y+h(y) = f(y)-h(y).f\prime(y)+\frac{1}{2} h^2y^2f\prime\prime(y)+o(h^2))\
&=\frac{1}{2}h^2f\prime\prime(y)\int y^2W(y)dy-f(Y)+o(h^2)\
&=\frac{1}{2}h^2f\prime\prime(y)\sigma^2_w+o(h^2)\
\text{where}\ &\sigma^2_w = \int y^2W(y) dy\
\text{Hence Bias of KDE is}
&=\frac{1}{2}h^2f\prime\prime(y)\sigma^2_w+o(h^2)
\end{aligned}
$$

\item[(b)]

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{From (a) above, we have the taylor expansion}\
&f(y+h(y) = f(y)-h(y).f\prime(y)+\frac{1}{2} h^2y^2f\prime\prime(y)+o(h^2))\
\text{using Var we have}\
&{\operatorname{Var}}(\hat f_n(y)= {\operatorname{Var}}(\frac{1}{nh}\sum^n_{i=1} W\frac{Y_i-y}{h}))\
&=\frac{1}{nh^2}{\operatorname{Var}}(W(\frac{Y_i-y}{h}))\
&\le\frac{1}{nh^2}E(W^2\frac{(Y_i-y)}{h})\
&=\frac{1}{nh^2}\int W^2\frac{(Y_i-y)}{h}f(y)dy\
&=\frac{1}{nh}\int W^2(y)f(y+hy)dy\
&=\frac{1}{nh}\int W^2(y)[f(y)+hyp\prime(y)+o(h)]dy\
&=\frac{1}{nh}(p(y).\int W^2(y)dy+o(h))\
&=\frac{1}{nh}p(y)\int W^2(y)dy+o(\frac{1}{nh})\
&=\frac{1}{nh}f(y)\alpha^2_w+o(\frac{1}{nh})\
&=\frac{1}{nh}f(y)\alpha_w\
\text{where}\ \alpha2_w=\int w^2(u)du
\end{aligned}
$$

\item[(c)]

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{From (a) and (b) above the MISE of KDE is given by:}\
&=\text{MISE}(f\prime_n) = \int MSE(f\prime_n(y))dy = E(\int (f\prime_n(y) - f(y))^2)dy\
&=\frac{1}{4}h^4\int \mid f\prime\prime(y)\mid^2dy\ \mu^2_w+\frac{1}{nh}\int f(y)dy\ \alpha^2_w+o(h^4)+o(\frac{1}{nh})\
&=\frac{\sigma^2_w}{4}h^4\int \mid f\prime\prime(y)\mid^2dy +\frac{\alpha^2_w}{nh}+o(h^4)+o(\frac{1}{nh})\
&=\frac{1}{4}h^4\sigma^4_w \int f\prime\prime^2 dy+\frac{1}{nh}\alpha(w)\
\text{where}\ \sigma(w) = \int \mu^2w(u)du.
\end{aligned}
$$
\item[(d)]

$$
\text{From (c) above the asymptotic mean squared error (AMSE) is}\
\begin{aligned}
&=\frac{\sigma^2_w}{4}.h^4.\int \mid f\prime\prime(y)\mid^2dy+\frac{\alpha^2_w}{nh}+o(h^4)+o(\frac{1}{nh})\
\text{Thus the otpimal smoothing bandwidth is chosen by minimizing AMSE}\
&h_{opt} = \left[ \frac{1}{n}.\frac{4}{\int \mid p(y)\prime\prime\mid^2dy}.\frac{\sigma^2_w}{\alpha^2_w})\right]^{\frac{1}{5}}\
&=\left[\frac{\psi(w)}{\beta(f)n}\right]^{\frac{1}{5}}\
&\text{where}\
&\psi(w)=\frac{\alpha(w)}{\sigma^4_w} \text{and}\ \beta(w)=\int f\prime\prime^2dy
\end{aligned}
$$
\item[(e)]

$$
\text{An approximate (1 -}\alpha) 100%\ \text{confidence interval for the Kernel density estimator}\
\begin{aligned}
&\hat f_n(y)=\frac{1}{nh}\sum^n_{i=1}W(\frac{Y_i-y}{h}) = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}Y_i\
\text{Thus KDE evaluated at}\ y_0\ \text{is a sample mean of Y}\
&\sqrt n \left( \frac{ \hat f_n(y)-E(\hat f_n(y)}{Var\ Y_i}\right)\frac{D}{\rightarrow}N(0,1)\
&Var(Y_i)=Var \left( \frac{1}{h}W\left(\frac{Y_i-y}{h}\right) \right)=\frac{1}{h}f(y)\sigma^2_w+o(\frac{1}{h})\
&\text{Diverges when h → 0, Thus, when h → 0, the asymptotic distribution of}\ \hat f_n(y)\ \text{is}\
&\sqrt {nh}(\hat f_n(y))-E(\hat f_n(y))\frac{D}{\rightarrow}N(0,f(y)\sigma^2_w)\
\text{Thus Confidence interval for the Kernel density estimator can be written as}\
\hat f_n(y) +- Z_{1-\alpha/2}.\sqrt {\hat f_n(y)\sigma^2_w}
\end{aligned}
$$

\textbf{Question 4}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(a)]

```
library(sm)
data(mtcars)
x <- mtcars$disp
hnorm(x)
hcv(x)
hsj(x)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

sm.density(x, h = hnorm(x), xlab = "Gross horsepower", lty=2)
sm.density(x, h = hcv(x), xlab = "Gross horsepower", add = T)
sm.density(x, h = hsj(x), xlab = "Gross horsepower", add  = T, lty = 3)
title(main="Displacement (cu.in.) per Gross horsepower (hp)")
```

The above density shows the displacement per gross horsepower with values normal optimal = 65.63941, Cross validation = 38.78734 and Sheather-Jones = 42.01607.

```
library(sm)
data(mtcars)
y <- mtcars$hp
hnorm(y)

hsj(y)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
sm.density(y, h = hnorm(x), xlab = "Gross horsepower", lty=2)
sm.density(y, h = hcv(x), xlab = "Gross horsepower", add = T)
sm.density(y, h = hsj(x), xlab = "Gross horsepower", add  = T, lty = 3)
title(main="Displacement (cu.in.) per Gross horsepower (hp)")
```

The graph gives the values for only normal optimal = 36.31171 and Sheather-Jones = 26.19646, and the graph seems smoother than displacement.

\item[(b)]

Comment: Is there any chance you could try to isolate the problem to a smaller section of your document in order to reduce the amount of code shown in the question? As it stands now there is quite a lot of code in the question that is hard to run for people other than you because it lacks crucial bits of code (document class, the preamble etc.). Try to reduce your problematic document to a small example document that is complete, but still shows the error.

Comment: If you type `foo #  foo` in rmarkdown, it is changed to  `foo \#  foo` in the LaTeX version. If you type `foo #  foo` in LaTeX will produce that error, because `#` without escaping is a special character to be used ONLY to define macros. Somewhere you make that mistake. I will start by reading the line 125 (of course, not the 125 line of the .Rmd file, but the 125 line of the  .tex version).